# NSMutableData to NSDictionary returning null

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledata

I'm writing a program that uses the Instagram API and I'm running into some issues with `NSMutableData and NSDictionary.`

Since I have to make multiple calls to the API, I decided to create a `NSMutableData object`, append smaller NSData objects to it and then turn the whole thing into an NSDictionary.

However, after I make a second call to `NSMutableData appendData NSData,` when I turn `NSMutableData` into an `NSDictionary`, the dictionary returns null.

Here's some of my code.

```
NSMutableData *userData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init]
NSData *feed = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/17636367/media/recent?access_token=%@",accessToken]]];
[userData appendData:feed];
NSData *moarData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/17636367/media/recent?access_token=%@&max_id=%@",accessToken, maxID]]];
[userData appendData:moarData];
NSDictionary *dictTwo = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:userData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",dictTwo);
```

dictTwo returns null. However, when I make only one call to appendData, the dictionary isn't empty.

Thanks.

Comment: check for accesstoken is nil.

Answer (score 2):

When you append two separate JSON responses they will not form a JSON.

You can test the final result to see if it is JSON or not with the following link:

[JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/)

You need to parse each query response separately and then apply manipulation on that data: (Ex NSMutableDictionary, NSMutableArray etc).

Answer (score 0):

The first call will return an array or dictionary. Assuming it is a dictionary you would get something like:

```
{"some":"data"}
```

This can be parsed correctly. When you make two calls you get:

```
{"some":"data"}{"other":"data"}
```

This is not valid JSON. You need to parse each item separately.